# Sometime I am getting error from exoplayer "Invalidate date format"

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

I am getting below error during playing live streaming video. It is working some time but it is working fine in web player and VLC player.

URL : https://30a-tv.com/feeds/zeasn/30atv.m3u8

anybody help me regarding this issue?

> Playback error
> androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
> at
> androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:713)
> at
> androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:683)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
> Caused by: androidx.media3.common.ParserException: Invalid date/time
> format: 2024-03-28T07:35:37R{contentIsMalformed=true, dataType=1}
> at androidx.media3.common.util.Util.parseXsDateTime(Util.java:1700)
> at
> androidx.media3.exoplayer.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistParser.parseMediaPlaylist(HlsPlaylistParser.java:851)
> at
> androidx.media3.exoplayer.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistParser.parse(HlsPlaylistParser.java:281)
> at
> androidx.media3.exoplayer.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistParser.parse(HlsPlaylistParser.java:69)
> at
> androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:184)
> at
> androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:421)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)